# How to perform Meteor.call on Session variable change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Here is what I have:

Templates:

```html
<body>
  {{> resultSession}}
  {{> resultMethod}}
</body>

<template name="resultSession">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <p>Session.get('length') returned {{returned}}</p>
</template>

<template name="resultMethod">
  <p>Meteor.call returned {{returned}}</p>
</template>
```

Client-side:

```js
Template.resultSession.events({
  'click button': function () {
    Session.set('length', Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
  }
});

Template.resultSession.helpers({
  returned: function () {
    return Session.get('length');
  }
});

Template.resultMethod.helpers({
  returned: function() {
    Meteor.call('returnArray', Session.get('length'), function (err, res) {
      return res.length;
    });
  }
});
```

Server-side:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'returnArray': function (length) {
    var arr = [];
    arr[length - 1] = 0;
    return arr;
  }
});
```

TL;DR

You can look at code and play with it here http://meteorpad.com/pad/AkBZq4ZFjJuQuzztz/Meteor.call-on-Session-change

As you can see, my method accepts `number` and returns the array with length equal to `number`.

The question is **how can I make** `Meteor.call` **fire each time** `Session` **variable changes?**

**P.S.** Values are returned to two different templates on purpose

Answer (score 2):

Your reactive code is working perfectly.
If you put a console.log in the Meteor.call you will see that the correct answer is coming back from the server.

```
Template.resultMethod.helpers({
  returned: function() {
    Meteor.call('returnArray', Session.get('length'), function (err, res) {
      console.log('it came back ' + res.length);
      return res.length;
    });
  }
});
```

I have put a Session variable into the return from the server, so now you can see that your reactive code works very simply - no need for complicated autorun stuff.

```
<template name="resultMethod">
  <p>Meteor.call returned {{returned}}</p>
</template>
```

Then in the resultMethod helper:

```
Template.resultMethod.helpers({
  returned: function() {
    Meteor.call('returnArray', Session.get('length'), function (err, res) {
      Session.set('fromServer', res.length + '');
    });
    return Session.get('fromServer');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like the response does not get returned because `Meteor.call` is async, and nothing is returned in the moment Method is called.

Comment: @Shtirlits Exactly, but I wasn't able to work out how to deal with it. I've now edited my answer, adding a Session variable. It all works.

Answer (score 1):

Like @saimeunt said, use [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)

Templates:

```
<body>
  {{> resultSession}}
  {{> resultMethod}}
</body>

<template name="resultSession">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <p>Session.get('length') returned {{returned}}</p>
</template>

<template name="resultMethod">
  <p>Meteor.call returned {{returned}}</p>
</template>
```

And code:

```
Template.resultMethod.rendered = function() {
    this.autorun(function (){
        Meteor.call('returnArray', Session.get('length'), function (err, res) {
            Session.set('result', res);
        });
    });
}

Template.resultSession.helpers({
  returned: function () {
    return Session.get('length');
  }
});

Template.resultMethod.helpers({
  returned: function() {
    return Session.get('result');
  }
});
```

Autorun inside rendered stops when the template is not rendered

Comment: But what if response from meteor method is too complex to be stored in session?

Comment: But they are locally scoped. If you need to store something globally, they won't work

Comment: What kind of response do you like to store in this variables?

Comment: You can store EJSON objects in session variables ([ref](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_set)), but I'm not sure the maximum size it can holds

Answer (score 0):

You could simply refactor your code to call the Meteor method on click event ?

```
Template.resultSession.events({
  'click button': function () {
    var length = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    Session.set('length', length);
    Meteor.call('returnArray', length, function (err, res) {
      Session.set('result', res.length);
    });
  }
});

Template.resultSession.helpers({
  returned: function () {
    return Session.get('length');
  }
});

Template.resultMethod.helpers({
  returned: function() {
    return Session.get('result');
  }
});
```

You could also use `Tracker.autorun` to track modifications of your `Session` variable and rerun arbitrary code.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var length = Session.get("length");
  console.log("length new value =", length);
});
```

Comment: I could, but I want to know if it is possible to call Metheor method on reactive var change

Comment: For example, if meteor method returns some complex object, that should not be stored in session var

Comment: hm, not sure how to use it then. Again, what if response from meteor method is too complex to be stored in session? Can I use `Tracker` inside template helpers?